# XMLHTTP request passing JSON string as raw post data

Tags: php, ajax, http-post

My JavasSript sends the request:

```
var jax = new XMLHttpRequest();
jax.open("POST", "http://localhost/some.php", true);
jax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
jax.send(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
jax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(jax.readyState === 4) { console.log(jax.responseText);  }
}
```

Right now all my php does is:

```
print_r($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
print_r($_POST);
```

The output from the raw post data is the object string, but the post array is empty.

```
{"name" : "somename", "innerObj" : {} ... }
Array
(
)
```

I need to get it in the proper format for the `$_POST` variable, and jquery isn't an option.

Comment: Have you tried `file_get_contents('php://input')`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right, since user1091949 posted my comment as an answer, here's the same thing again, so OP can choose who's answer to approve (if it worked):

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

At this point, `$json` will be an instance of the `stdClass`... If you prefer an associative array, just pass a second parameter to `json_decode('{"json":"string"}', true);`

BTW: *Never*, **Ever** use the forbidden error-suppressor of *death*: `@`. Errors are there to *help* you, not to annoy you...

Comment: I posted your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the raw post data:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
  exit;
}

$postdata = @file_get_contents("php://input");
$json = json_decode($postdata, true);
```

`$json` will be an associative array containing your JSON data.