# How to read JSON data using PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, curl

I am trying to read data send by curl request but I cant able to read that.
example

```
curl -x post -d '{user:"test", pwd:"123"}' http://localhost/api/login/
```

and in PHP code

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
```

but always I am getting a null value, how to fix this issue?

Comment: sorry use this `json_decode`..like `print_r(json_decode($curldata))`..[reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: i tried json_decode($_POST) but its also failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the post name in curl. Right now you're submitting JSON, but without a name. ([Link to curl man pages](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html))

```
-d data={JSON}
```

Then in php you can load and decode the JSON: ([Link to json_decode in the php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php))

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
$user = $data['user'];
```

---

If you want to continue sending data without using key/value pairs, you can keep your existing implementation of curl and use the following in PHP:

```
$data = @file_get_contents("php://input");
$json = json_decode($data, true);
```

This was taken from: [XMLHTTP request passing JSON string as raw post data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114380/xmlhttp-request-passing-json-string-as-raw-post-data)

Comment: first of all thanks for answering my question.is there any other way to read the data without assigning to a variable?becoz the customer wants the api calls like the exact way i have specified.

Comment: I've just updated the solution to read from php://input so that you don't need to modify the API call